# Do I need to know php and mySQL to convert static website to wordpress theme

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have created a static website using xhtml, css and jquery. I have got zero knowledge or understanding of how php and mySQL works. Is it possible to create fully functional theme for wordpress? And how about using frameworks?

Comment: PHP is required. MySQL - not so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll be able to do it but you'd need some basic at least PHP knowledge to get going.

Start out having a look at the Wordpress Codex - http://codex.wordpress.org/Main_Page.

It's full of all the information you'll need to get started.

From there have a look at an existing Wordpress theme. Try making small changes to that and see how you get on.

You won't really need MYSQL as Wordpress runs it's own, easy to understand querys.

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Anything's possible with enough time.

At the very least you will need to learn PHP, but you can do this by downloading an existing theme and modifying it to suit your desired HTML output.